# Margin top of first span not working

Tags: css, margin, html

```
<div class ="cards">
  <span id="cardtitle">
    Chance 
  </span>
  <span id="cardinfo">
    Your ass is going to jail.
  </span>
</div>
```

```
.cards{
  background: #F8F8F8 ;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
#cardtitle, #cardinfo{
  background: #ffcc00;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Okay the margin-top on `#cardinfo` works but `#cardtitle` doesn't. The problem seems to be the first element, as the problem reverses if i reverese the 2 spans.

Comment: That's because of [margin collapse](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Comment: no its not duplicate because the margin-top is working for me albeit not for the first span element.

Comment: @EltonFrederik Yes, I realized after I closed, so sorry for that, I have answered anyways the moment I realized

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you are facing, is called *[collapsed margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)*, hence either you can use `position: relative;` with `top` set to `10px` or use `overflow: auto;` on the parent element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxd3y/) *(Using `overflow: auto;`)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxd3y/1/) *(Using `position: relative;` + `top: 10px;` and `top: 20px;`)*

`position: relative;` method will require you to set the `top` separately as it will move your element, though it physically reserves the space, hence you will have to double up for the second one..

Comment: @ Mr Alien, it worked, but can I ask why I needed `overflow: auto;` i thought that was by default. My div was big enough to accomodate the 2 spans...?

Comment: @EltonFrederik It defines new block formatting context, you can also use `overflow: hidden;` too... either one you like

Comment: You may use position:absolute and then top, right, left and bottom to position the element as per your choice.